# Displaying the value of a function in a view (Play Framework 2)

Tags: playframework-2.0

I just started messing around with **Play 2**. I recently learned how to create a model (`User`) and how to show it in the view (please let me know if there's any bad practice):

**models/User.scala:**

```
package models

case class User(id: Long, name: String)

object User {
  var user = User(
    id = 1L,
    name = "Mark"
  )

  def greeting = TODO

}
```

**controllers/Application.scala:**

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.User

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  def hello =  Action {
    Ok(views.html.hello(User.user))
  }

}
```

**hello.scala.html:**

```
@(user: User)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

  <h2>@user.id</h2>
  <h3>@user.name</h3>

}
```

Now, I want to display the output of a function in the view.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Sorry, probably I missed something in your question or didn't understand it but first answer that I can imagine is: `<h3>Hello my name is @user.name</h3>` What exactly you want to achieve? Try to specify :)

Comment: @biesior Yeah, well, that would be the same. But I want to know how to do it with a function (like, `def greeting`...) I want to know how to display the output of a function in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use another view ([tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTemplateUseCases)) which as you probably  know is also just a Scala function:

/app/views/tags/userName.scala.html

```
@(user: User)
My Name is @user.name
```

So you can use the `userName` function in your `index` view

```
@(user: User)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

    <h2>@user.id</h2>
    <h3>User @user.name said: @tags.userName(user)</h3>

}
```

De facto the same you can also use functions from your models and controllers by just specyfying it as:

```
@SomeController.someFunction(user)
@SomeModel.someFunction(user)
```

And if your class isn't placed in `controllers` or `models` packages (which are imported into the views by default) you just need to use  full qualified path:

```
@utils.MyDateFormaters.formatDay(user.birthDay)
```

Comment: by the way, could you give me an example of defining a function in the model and displaying it in the view?

Comment: AFAIK, it is really bad practice to call a model's function from a view (Separation of Concerns, tight coupling)

Comment: @nico_ekito could you give me an example of how it should be called?

Comment: It is the role of your controller to call methods from the model, and then pass the result to the view.

Comment: You mean something like this? `object Application extends Controller {

  var user = User(
    id = 1L,
    name = "Mark"
  )`

Comment: @nico_ekito, how about ie. custom getters? they are functions too, they also shouldn't be accessed from the view ?

Comment: I don't think so. The view should make any "calculation" (ie business algorithm). The aim of the view is to "render", not to make any computation.